# Obtener el enésimo elemento de una concatenación ordenada de arreglos

Tags: javascript, array, optimización

Para [este ejercicio](https://www.codewars.com/kata/591120432e6009420b00002d/train/javascript) tengo que obtener el enésimo elemento de una concatenación ordenada de arreglos, es decir

si

```
array1 = [1, 3, 4], array2 = [2, 6, 8], n = 5
```

entonces debo regresar 8

porque

```
                |
                v
 0  1  2  3  4  5
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8]
```

Intenté de esta manera

```
let twoArraysNthElement = (array1, array2, n) =>
  array1.concat(array2).sort((a, b)=>a - b)[n]
```

Pero el desempeño no es lo mejor, ya que obtengo la solución en mayor tiempo del esperado por la plataforma, ¿Cómo podría modificar mi solución para obtener mejor desempeño?

## Intentos

```
function twoArraysNthElement(array1, array2, n) {
  let joint = array1;
  joint.push(...array2);

  joint.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });
  return joint[n];
}
```

Si bien el desempeño parece ser mejor, como `array1` y `array2` en mis pruebas unitarias son demasiado grandes obtengo el error

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿en qué te basas para decir que el desempeño de tu solución no es la mejor? Es que la veo y creo que está bien implementado todo, saludos.

Comment: vale, ya lo agrego

Comment: ¿Cual es la intención de esta pregunta? ¿Cobrar los puntos de codewars? Si realmente te intriga la respuesta puedes ver la "solución" de ese kata dándote por vencido y renunciado a los puntos. Si lo que no entiendes es por que la "solución" funciona entonces creo que deberías de colocar en la pregunta la "solución".

Comment: @x3k_js no necesito los puntos pues ya estoy en el ranking de esa página, solamente quiero aprender y beneficiar a mi gente latina en el proceso. Siendo sinceros lo más probable es que halle la respuesta por mí mismo y la comparta aquí.

Comment: Perdona, creo que no ha sido la manera correcta de expresar mi comentario. Solo quería decir que la solución la puedes encontrar mediante el propio codewars y despues si no entiendes algo o no te parecen correctas esas soluciones hacer la pregunta especifica. Leyéndolo de nuevo me ha sonado muy brusco... perdona :)

Comment: Creo que la forma de solucionarlo es tener dos índices, uno para cada array, e ir aumentando uno u otro según convenga hasta que su suma sea igual al índice que buscas

Comment: @PabloLozano creo que el problema es que vienen desordenados por defecto

Comment: No, ambos arrays vienen ordenados: *Given two **sorted** arrays of integers(array1 and array2) and an integer n, find the nth (0-based) element of their sorted union*

Comment: Una forma más eficiente es usando un método de aproximación por defecto. Si me da tiempo te publico una respuesta. La idea es usar el método propuesto por @PabloLozano, pero haciendo una pequeña mejora.

Comment: @PabloLozano podrías por favor agregar tu comentario como respuesta para aceptarlo? Gracias a él lo pude solucionar. Yo me encargo de editarlo y ponerle el código con el que lo resolví.

Comment: @MauricioContreras sería genial si lo compartes, así trato de optimizar la solución que ya tengo y te doy tus puntos. Saludos cordiales.

Answer (score 2):

La solución propuesta por @PabloLozano (y muchas de las que se pueden apreciar en la página de [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/591120432e6009420b00002d/solutions/javascript)) proponen llevar la cuenta de los iteradores para cada `array`, hasta obtner `n`. Si bien esto es bastante intuitivo y de plano funciona, se puede mejorar.

**ANÁLISIS**

Analicemos un poco antes de pasar al código.

Se trata de obtener el valor de la posición `n` en el `array` resultante de la concatenación ordenada de `array1` y `array2`, donde:

```
0 <= n <= array1.length + array2.length - 1
```

Para decirlo de otro modo, `n` está entre 0 y el tamaño del `array` resultante menos 1 (ambos incluidos).

Ahora, la propuesta de solución plantea iterar entre `0` y `n`, mientras a su vez vamos "ordenando" los valores de menor a mayor. Para esto debemos recordar en qué índice de `array1` y de `array2` estamos parados para ir comparando sus valores entre si.

La lógica sería algo parecida a esto:

```js
const twoArraysNthElement = (array1, array2, n) => {
  let indice1 = 0;
  let indice2 = 0;
  let nthElement;
  for(let i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    if(array1[indice1] < array2[indice2]) {
      nthElement = array1[indice1];
      indice1++;
    } else {
      nthElement = array2[indice2];
      indice2++;
    }
  return nthElement;
}
```

Esto tiene un problema, y es que `n` se basa en la dimensión de `array1.length + array2.length - 1`. Además ambos `array's` no necesariamente tienen el mismo tamaño.

¿Ven el error?

Precisamente pensando en solucionar dicho error, encontré una forma de mejorar la búsqueda (primera aproximación). Y es que aún existen seguramente otro tipo de mejoras en la forma de hallar una solución.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Las primeras preguntas que vinieron a mi mente fueron:

- **¿Debo considerar la diferencia en el tamaño de los `array's`?**
- **¿Cómo iterar cuando `n` es menor que el tamaño del `array` más pequeño?**
- **¿Cómo iterar cuando `n` es mayor que el tamaño del `array` más pequeño?**

Ante estas preguntas me planteo de forma gráfica lo siguiente:

```js
array1 = [1, 3, 5, 6]
array2 = [0, 2, 4, 7, 8]


n = 2

   nthElement
       |
       v
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

n = 5
            nthElement
                |
                v
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Suponiendo que he corregido el error planteado originalmente, es muy rápido calcular el segundo elemento del `array` concatenado usando la lógica anterior.

Debemos recorrer desde 0 hasta 2 y verificar en el primer y segundo `array` sus valores para ir ordenando. En este contexto hablamos de 3 iteraciones.

Sin embargo, para obtener el `n-ésimo` elemento cuando `n` vale 5, tenemos 6 iteraciones. Y no sólo tenemos las 6 iteraciones sino que debemos comprobar si hemos superado la longitud de alguno de los `array` en la búsqueda.

Pero si iteramos de derecha a izquierda, nos ahorramos 2 iteraciones. Por lo tanto es más eficiente. Y aunque debemos igualmente comprobar si hemos superado la longitud de alguno de los dos `array's`, sigue siendo esto más eficiente.

Lo primero que se me ocurrió fue determinar cuál es el `array` más pequeño y cuál el más grande, y si ambos fuesen del mismo tamaño (dimensión), daría igual que uno se llamase `corto` y otro `largo`.

```
[shorter, longer] = array1.length <= array2.length ? [array1, array2] : [array2, array1];
```

Ahora ya tengo una forma de aplicar la lógica sobre el valor de `n` vs. el tamaño del `array` más corto.

Cuando `n` es menor que la dimensión o tamaño del `array` más corto, no debo preocuparme de salir de la dimensión del `Array`. Y puedo directamente hacer el ordenamiento.

¿Y cómo hago esto?

Usaré el viejo bucle `for` y algunas variables.

**Caso `n < shorter.length`:**

Usaremos 3 variables para almacenar: *índice del `array` más pequeño, índice del `array` más grande y valor del elemento correspondiente a la iteración `i-esima` del `array` resultante de la concatenación ordenada*.

Al final no necesitamos crear un `array` concatenado, simplemente iterar los elementos de `array1` y `array2` tal como aparecerían en el `array` concatenado.

```js
// caso n < shorter.length
let shorter_index = 0;
let longer_index = 0;
let nthElement;
// iteramos desde 0 hasta n inclusive
for(let i = 0; i <=n; i++) {
  //comprobamos cuál elemento es menor entre shorter[shorter_index] y longer[longer_index]
  if(shorter[shorter_index] < longer[longer_index]) {
    nthElement = shorter[shorter_index];
    shorter_index++;
  } else {
    nthElement = longer[longer_index];
    longer_index++;
  }
}
return nthElement;
```

Con esto ya tenemos el caso inicial en el que `n < shorter.length`. Ahora veamos cómo atacamos el caso en que `n > shorter.length`.

**Caso `n > shorter.length`:**

Para este caso tendremos las misma 3 variables, pero vamos a recorrer de derecha a izquierda el `array` concatenado. Para ello debemos saber la dimensión del mismo:

```
const top = shorter.length + longer.length - 1;
```

Así `top` nos da el punto de partida y `n` será nuestro punto de llegada.

Como vamos a recorrer el `array` concatenado al revés, los `array` que lo componen también debemos recorrerlos desde la derecha hacia la izquierda, y los índices en este caso, en vez de aumentar, van a disminuir hasta llegar a cero como máximo.

```js
let shorter_index = shorter.length - 1;
let longer_index = longer.length - 1;
let nthElement;
const top = shorter.length + longer.length - 1;
// vamos a recorrer de derecha a izquierda y debemos diminuir el valor del iterando
for(let i = top; i >= n; i--) {
  // debemos comprobar que el índice más corto no se ha hecho negativo
  if(short_index >= 0) {
    // ahora buscamos el mayor de los dos valores
    if(shorter[short_index] > longer[long_index]) {
      nthElement = shorter[short_index];
      short_index--;
    } else {
      nthElement = longer[long_index];
      long_index--;
    }
  } else {
    // si ya hemos recorrido todo el array más corto, sólo quedan elementos del más largo
    nthelement = longer[long_index];
    long_index--;
  }
}
return nthElement;
```

Con esto ya tenemos el algoritmo para hallar lo que nos están pidiendo.

El código final puede verse así:

```js
const twoArraysNthElement = (array1, array2, n) => {
  const [shorter, longer] = array1.length <= array2.length ? [array1, array2] : [array2, array1];
  if(n < shorter.length) {
    let short_index = 0;
    let long_index = 0;
    let nthElement;
    for(let i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
      if(shorter[short_index] < longer[long_index]) {
        nthElement = shorter[short_index];
        short_index++;
      } else {
        nthElement = longer[long_index];
        long_index++;
      }
    }
    return nthElement;
  } else {
    let short_index = shorter.length - 1;
    let long_index = longer.length - 1;
    let nthElement;
    let top = shorter.length + longer.length - 1;
    for(let i = top; i >= n; i--) {
      if(short_index >= 0) {
        if(shorter[short_index] > longer[long_index]) {
          nthElement = shorter[short_index];
          short_index--;
        } else {
          nthElement = longer[long_index];
          long_index--;
        }
      } else {
        nthElement = longer[long_index];
        long_index--;
      }
    }
    return nthElement;
  }
}

const array1 = [6,19,21,30,34,35,44,48];
const array2 = [3,4,5,9,14,16,25,32,36,37,41,53];

const n = 11;
console.log('Debe mostrar 32:');
console.log(twoArraysNthElement(array1, array2, n));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea lo suficientemente clara para entender el propósito del ejercicio.

Hay una forma de mejorar la eficiencia, y es tomando en cuenta si `n` está en la primera mitad o en la segunda mitad del `array` concatenado y aplicar esta optimización para realmente hacer la menor cantidad de iteraciones posibles.

**MEJORA**

Mi última linea anterior me motivó a implementar la mejora para realmente hacer el proceso en la menor cantidad de iteraciones posibles. Por lo tanto, me permití refactorizar la función anterior para iterar desde 0 a `n` si esta se encuentra en la primera mitad del `array` concatenado. E iterar al revés en caso de que `n` se encuentre en la segunda mitad del `array`. Para ello igualmente debo tomar en cuenta el tamaño de ambos `array` para no obtener valores indefinidos.

La función quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```js
const twoArraysNthElement = (array1, array2, n) => {
  const [shorter, longer] = array1.length <= array2.length ? [array1, array2] : [array2, array1];
  const middle = Math.floor((shorter.length + longer.length) / 2);
  let nthElement;
  if(n < middle) {
    let short_index = 0;
    let long_index = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
      if(short_index < shorter.length) {
        nthElement = shorter[short_index] < longer[long_index] ? shorter[short_index++] : longer[long_index++];
      } else {
        nthElement = longer[long_index++];
      }
    }
  } else {
    let short_index = shorter.length - 1;
    let long_index = longer.length - 1;
    let top = shorter.length + longer.length - 1;
    for(let i = top; i >= n; i--) {
      if(short_index >= 0) {
        nthElement = shorter[short_index] > longer[long_index] ? shorter[short_index--] : longer[long_index--];
      } else {
        nthElement = longer[long_index--];
      }
    }
  }
  return nthElement;
}

const array1 = [15,16,21,25,29,31];
const array2 = [5,8,12,18,28];

const n = 10;
console.log('Debe mostrar 31:');
console.log(twoArraysNthElement(array1, array2, n));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```